# C++/R: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, r, macos, clang

I am trying to install and run a [this](https://github.com/beechung/Latent-Factor-Models) project. It is written in C++ and R. I follow the instructions and when I type the make command, I get this error:

> R CMD SHLIB src/C/util.c src/C/factor_model_util.c src/C/pagerank.c src/C/hierarchical.c src/C/factor_model_multicontext.c src/C/factor_model_util2.cpp -o lib/c_funcs.so
> clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o lib/c_funcs.so src/C/util.o src/C/factor_model_util.o src/C/pagerank.o src/C/hierarchical.o src/C/factor_model_multicontext.o src/C/factor_model_util2.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -Wall -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
>
> ld: library not found for -lgfortran
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make[1]: *** [lib/c_funcs.so] Error 1
>
> make: *** [c_funcs] Error 1

Here is my "clang --version" results:

> Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
>
> Thread model: posix

Does anyone know what should I do? I saw the answers about xcode projects, but here I am only trying to use make for compiling.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the directory the linker is complaining about exists? If not, you'll have to point it to the right directory.

Comment: If you mean this directory: **-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2** , no I don't have it. I don't know even what -L means at the beginning of the address

Comment: -L sets a linker path, the linker will look for certain files in that particular directory. You'll have to figure out where you need to point that path to.

Comment: So what is the right directory?

Comment: You'll have to set that based on your machine's configuration.

Comment: I understand, I mean what should I point it to? Like should I point it to gcc (under /usr/bin/gcc)?

Comment: btw, why the osx tag if it's a windows question?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, and solved it by installing the [newer gfortran 4.8.2](http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2). For some reason the [main page](http://r.research.att.com/tools/) links to version 4.3.2, which causes this issue (I believe because R binaries are actually built with a newer gfortran).

Comment: I am trying to install it on windows machine. My gcc veresion is 4.9.2. I do not know what the gfrotran is or should be. Is there any link for windows version?

Comment: no idea, sorry, I don't use Windows for package development

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I posted two different questions and got confused for some reason. It is an os x project. My bad.